# 3D Touch quick action

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, 3dtouch

I'm trying to implement a quick action with 3D touch on the app's icon and something very strange is happening.

The icon quick action I'm doing is supposed to open the app with the root view controller, hide some views, show other views and check for updates. And everything works fine until I go to another view controller and get back to the main one, push the home button and try to quick action the same.

If I move to another view controller get back to the main one, and try the quick action, the views will no longer hide/unhide, but the check for updates method are working normally. Also the code for the hide/unhide is being called, but it doesn't take effect.

Tried performing the hide/unhide method with performOnMainThread, tried putting it in dispatch on main thread, with a delay, and nothing works.

AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler
{
    if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"com.systems"])
    {
        self.shortcutAction = kShortcutActionSystems;
    }
}
```

MainViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(appBecameActive)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}


- (void)appBecameActive
{
    if ([appDelegate.shortcutAction isEqualToString:kShortcutActionUpdates])
    {
        if (authenticated)
        {
            [self showUpdates:nil];
            [self checkForUpdates:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            [self showUpdates:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

checkForUpdates: is always called and always performs the requests.
showUpdates: is always called but the hide/unhide parts are not working if I move to another view controller and the come back.

EDIT:

In showUpdates: I call another method:

```
- (IBAction)showUpdates:(id)sender
{
    if (authenticated)
    {
        //[self showUpdatesAuthenticatedView];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showUpdatesAuthenticatedView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];


- (void)showUpdatesAuthenticatedView
{
    _updatesTableView.dataSource = self;
    [_updatesTableView reloadData];

    _updatesIndicator.hidden = NO;
    _systemsIndicator.hidden = YES;

    _updatesTableView.hidden = NO;
    _backTableView.hidden = NO;
    _checkUpdatesOutlet.hidden = NO;

    _systemTableView.hidden = YES;
    _loginAskView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Where is hide/unhide code here ? :o

Comment: I added the hide method.

Comment: Can u please post showUpdates method. How is your showUpdatesAuthenticatedView called ??

Comment: I tried calling showUpdates: on the main thread, with dispatch, then showUpdatesAuthenticatedView also on the main thread and dispatch main queue, still nothing